# Automated Email to only send once

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, automationstudio

I have a list of subscribers inside a data extension. One of the fields is GamePoints. If a subscriber has more than 10 GamePoints I want to send an e-mail to remind them.

I am able to do this using the Automation Studio. This job will run every hour to check for subscribers with more than 10 GamePoints.

The problem is that once a subscriber reaches 10 GamePoints he receives an e-mail every time the job is running. But what I want is to limit this reminder per subscriber to only once every two weeks. Is this possible? (running the job only once per two weeks is not an option).

Comment: an oldie, but a good solution here is to use `UPSERT` on the email send and mark that the subscribers has received the email with a date stamp... You can then add a condition that only those who are GamePoints > 10 AND "Send Date" > 14 days ago, or is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest implementing an [Exclusion Script](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000213980&language=en_US) that excludes subscribers if  `GamePoints > 10`.

```
Not empty(AttributeValue("GamePoints")) and GamePoints > 10
```

Exclusion Scripts are defined on in UI-Send and Triggered Send Definitions.  They have to be enabled by SFMC Support.  No charge.

Answer (score -1):

But be careful using exclusion scripts counts as an email send.

Technically though you are killing the email, SF still charges as 1 email sent.

Thanks